# setLatestEventInfo Method is Removed in API 23 in Android

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher; 

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)

            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("msg", message);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |

            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent =

            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

**How to resolve `setLatestEventInfo` method in this code with API 23?**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Here is the code you will need to make this work and compile.

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

// Called when a broadcast is made targeting this class
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    createNotification(context, "Times Up", "5 Seconds Has Passed", "Alert");

}

public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgText, String msgAlert){

    // Define an Intent and an action to perform with it by another application
    PendingIntent notificIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    // Builds a notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ntt_logo_24_24)
                    .setContentTitle(msg)
                    .setTicker(msgAlert)
                    .setContentText(msgText);

    // Defines the Intent to fire when the notification is clicked
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificIntent);

    // Set the default notification option
    // DEFAULT_SOUND : Make sound
    // DEFAULT_VIBRATE : Vibrate
    // DEFAULT_LIGHTS : Use the default light notification
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    // Auto cancels the notification when clicked on in the task bar
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Gets a NotificationManager which is used to notify the user of the background event
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Post the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

  }
```

.setLatestEventInfo was depreciated in API 11. Hope this helps.